# Trying to use JWT Authorization in dotnet 6 Minimal API. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a JWT, returned from my authentication API which has the following filled out:

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "sysadmin",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname": "",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname": "",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Administrators",
  "exp": 1667578481,
  "iss": "ISSUER",
  "aud": "AUDIENCE"
}
```

I've validated the JWT at jwt.io, and everything checks out.

In my setup I have :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts =>
    {
        opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "ISSUER",
            ValidAudience = "AUDIENCE",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
        };
    });
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And I have API endpoints decorated with `[Authorize]`:

```
[Authorize]
IResult GetForcast()
{
  ...
}
```

When I test it I just get a 401 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending the authorization header back?

Comment: Yes, unless I'm doing that wrong... 
`curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:44394/weatherforecast' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIn....`

Comment: Does `-H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciO....` fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call your service make sure you have a correct `Authorization` header.

`Authorization: Bearer <token>`